# Salesforce Data Extensions in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

Is it possible to use SF Data Extensions in Journey Builder and Automation Studio?

We basically need to send tracking data to Sales Cloud and to do that, it seems the Data Extensions need to be in Salesforce Data Extension folder and have the 18-digit SF Contact/Lead ID.

Manual sends work fine, despite being a 2-step process.
However how can we use them with Journeys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using Marketing Cloud Connect ? If yes all you need is 18 digit contact / lead id. When you configure email send in journeys you will have a option "Send Tracking Data to Sales Cloud" and emails gets logged under IER in sales cloud.

Your DE has to be in Data Extensions folder, even if it's a Salesforce Data Extension. Just move them manually.

Comment: Hey! Yes, we are using MC Connect. We do have the 18-digit Contact ID as one of the fields, but it's not the Subscriber Key, which it must be, correct?

However are you saying that the Data Extension does not have to be under Salesforce Data Extension folder in order for the tracking data to sync to SF?

Comment: Journey Builder is the exception to the rule - when making regular guided sends you will want your Data Extension to be in the Salesforce Data Extensions folder, but Journey Builder can send tracking information back to Salesforce and as a rule, it must be located in the standard Data Extensions folder.

Comment: Anon is spot on! but also Atheri, the Contact or Lead Id must be the field that relates to all subscribers. This is the way through which Journey builder finds the right person at the top, and the ID that will populate in the system tables, through which tracking data is sent to sales / service cloud. Therefore, 18 digit field containing Lead or Contact Id that is used as the relationship to all subscribers. That is the requirement.